# c# Outlook addin forcibly move the cursor to the end of email body

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I am adding a table to the email body programmatically. I would like to move the cursor below the table after insertion. I've tried SendKeys.Send("{PGDN 10}") and have had some success but I'm not sold on the idea that this is the best way to approach it.

Are there any other ways to forcibly move the cursor down to the end of the email body?

Comment: Have you tried using the WordEditor to do this? You should be able to get the WordEditor from the MailItem object via GetInspector.WordEditor. I believe you can do something like editor.Range(index, index).Select()

Comment: Works like a charm Jesse! Do you happen to know how to get the index of the last char of the email?

Comment: I believe you can grab the body from the mailItem.Body property. This property might include things like the signature. Maybe consider precompiling the body first, then append the original body to the email so you can get the index from the start to the original body of the email (signature).

Comment: I feel like it's close but that isn't quite doing it for me. I've tried mailitem.Body.Count() and had some success with that but it seems to be out of bounds for the index.

Comment: See my newest edit for an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The office model allows you to fetch the WordEditor object if you have access to the MailItem object. Once you have the WordEditor object, you can perform a Range and select to put the cursor in a specific position in the document. There might be an easier way, but this is a quick example.

```
var editor = oMailItem.GetInspector.WordEditor;
editor.Range(1,1).Select();
```

**Edit**

If you'd like to set the cursor to the last position in the body before the signature, you can do something like the sample below.

```
var originalBody = oMailItem.HTMLBody;
oMailItem.HTMLBody = newBodyHTMLStringCompiled;
var wordDocument = oMailItem.GetInspector.WordEditor;
var endingPosition = wordDocument.Content.End;

// This will append the original signature
oMailItem.HTMLBody += originalBody;

// Set the range for the cursor
wordDocument.Range(endingPosition, endingPosition).Select();
```

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful response! What is "newBodyHTMLStringCompiled"?

Comment: var endingPosition = wordDocument.Content.End - 1; solved my problem. Thanks for this example!